# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
class DetailsSummaryViewStore {

  prop1: number;
  prop2: string;



  private setData(key: keyof DetailsSummaryViewStore, data: any ) {
    this[key] = data;
  }
}
```

In another method of this class I calling setData and am trying to set the values of the class properties after doing a api call. What is a right way to do this.

Current error is thrown in this[key]

Answer (score 1):

I think its should be

```
class DetailsSummaryViewStore { 
      prop1: number;
      prop2: string; 
      private setData(key: keyof DetailsSummaryViewStore, data: any ) { 
            (this[key] as any) = data; 
      } 
}
```

Comment: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'DetailsSummaryViewStore'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'DetailsSummaryViewStore'.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange, it seems to be related to having number properties.

This is fine:

```
class DetailsSummaryViewStore {
    prop: string;

    constructor() {
        this.prop = 'stuff'
    }

    setData(key: keyof DetailsSummaryViewStore, data: any) {
        this[key] = data;
    }
}
```

This causes the error you are seeing:

```
class DetailsSummaryViewStore {
    prop: number;

    constructor() {
        this.prop = 1
    }

    setData(key: keyof DetailsSummaryViewStore, data: any) {
        this[key] = data;
        // ERROR: Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated question. I do have ``stuff``but I can't set their value in constructor

Comment: Oh that's weird, if you modify this to `stuff: number`, Typescript throws the error you're seeing. When there is not number property, it seems to work...

Comment: I'm not sure why Typescript complains like this. I would recommend using @iamhuynq's answer, which still has the correct type for the `setData` parameters at least. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60791253/7486612